# Automatically add curly braces to single line if/for/while etc statements in IntelliJ for java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, format

I want to add curly braces in IntelliJ to single line statements. 
Lets say I have:

```
if(x)
  print(y)
```

I want IntelliJ to automatically format that to:

```
if(x){
  print(y)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Java -> Wrapping and braces -> if/while/for() statement -> Force braces -> Always`

Answer (score 4):

Under File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java on the tab "Wrapping and Braces" under "'if()' statement", set "Force braces" to "Always". And the same for "'for()' statement", "'while()' statement" and "'do ... while' statement".

When you reformat (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), or complete the statement using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, IntelliJ will add the braces for you.

Comment: I tried that and when I press command + option + L it says that the code is already formatted

Comment: It may be some other configurations on my project. I will have a look. Thank you for the suggestion though